# Accessing a column with spaces in the column name from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Ruby 2.1.5
Rails 4.1
```

I've inherited some code with where some of the columns have spaces in them. How do I access these columns from a view. Example:

```
Table: expenses
Columns: Jan 2015
         Feb 2015
```

In expenses_controller.rb, I have

```
@epxenses = Expense
```

In views/expenses/index.html.erb, the following would not work:

```
@expenses.each do |e|
  e.jan 2010
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing that activerecord may snake_case the column the name `e.jan_2010`. Sounds like a pretty awful database design, you have my sympathies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it using `[]` or `attributes[]`:

```
expense = Expense.last
expense['Jan 2015'] 
expense.attributes['Jan 2015']
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails/Active record should not generate migrations with spaces in the field names, or if you specifically tell it to I would be curious as to why because it will likely be inconvenient going forward. If you are hooking up to a database that was created outside of AR, maybe you would benefit from aliasing the field names in your data models.

```
alias_attribute :new_column_name, :column_name_in_db
```

Comment: Rails had no problem generating migrations. I suspected that it should not have but when I looked at the migration files, something like: add_column :expenses, 'Jan 2010, :integer worked fine. Thanks for the aliasing suggestion, I will try it out